# Appending value to hashtable

Tags: java, android, encryption, hash

I am implementing an encryption decryption application.for that i'm using a hash table to store the encrypted value with a hint.while decrypting i need to get hash table values.but here i am getting only a single key and its value in hash table.here storeMessage() is for storing hashtable to file and getMessage() is for retriving.can anyone help me to find the proper solution.

Thanks in advance

**For storing hash table to file**

```
public boolean storeMessage(byte[] bt,String hint){
        boolean status=false;

    byte[][] valuePair=null;
    java.util.Set<String> set=null;
    java.util.Iterator<String> itr=null;
    ObjectOutputStream objOut=null;
    try {

        System.out.println("jhkj:"+ht);
        if(ht==null) 
        ht=new Hashtable<String, byte[]>();

        ht.put(hint, bt);

        keyPair=new String[ht.size()];
        valuePair=new byte[keyPair.length][1];

        set=ht.keySet();
        itr=set.iterator();
        int i=0;
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            keyPair[i]=itr.next();
            valuePair[i]=ht.get(keyPair[i]);
            i++;
        }

    if(!new java.io.File("store.db").exists()) 
        new java.io.File(path+ "/store.db").createNewFile();  


    objOut=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path+ "/store.db",true));
    objOut.writeObject(keyPair);
    objOut.writeObject(valuePair);
    objOut.close();
    status=true;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    finally{            
    }
    return status;
}
```

**To get a hashtable from file**

```
java.util.Hashtable<String, byte[]> getMessage(){

    byte[][] valuePair=null;
    ObjectInputStream objIn=null;
    ht=new Hashtable<String, byte[]>();
    try{
        objIn=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(con.getFilesDir().getParentFile().getPath()+ "/store.db"));
        keyPair=(String[]) objIn.readObject();
        valuePair=(byte[][]) objIn.readObject();

        int i=0;
        while(i<keyPair.length){
            ht.put(keyPair[i], valuePair[i]);
            i++;
        }


    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
    {           
        ht=new Hashtable<String, byte[]>();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>"+e);
    }
    finally{
        try {
            objIn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
        }
    }
    System.out.println("hash table:"+ht);
    return ht;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time when you store hashtable you should first get the current stored table and then add new entry to it before storing it.

For ex:

```
public boolean storeMessage(byte[] bt,String hint){
        boolean status=false;

    byte[][] valuePair=null;
    java.util.Set<String> set=null;
    java.util.Iterator<String> itr=null;
    ObjectOutputStream objOut=null;
    try {

        System.out.println("jhkj:"+ht);
        ht=getMessage();//<--Here you are trying to get current hashtable 
        if(ht==null) 
           ht=new Hashtable<String, byte[]>();

        ht.put(hint, bt);

        keyPair=new String[ht.size()];
        valuePair=new byte[keyPair.length][1];

        set=ht.keySet();
        itr=set.iterator();
        int i=0;
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            keyPair[i]=itr.next();
            valuePair[i]=ht.get(keyPair[i]);
            i++;
        }

    if(!new java.io.File("store.db").exists()) 
        new java.io.File(path+ "/store.db").createNewFile();  


    objOut=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path+ "/store.db",true));
    objOut.writeObject(keyPair);
    objOut.writeObject(valuePair);
    objOut.close();
    status=true;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    finally{            
    }
    return status;
}
```